maturin build fails after adding --sdist build option
After I added --sdist option to maturin build, I started to get the following error.
D:\a\_temp\9ef7b44d-af79-42ba-9bdc-1eeb97741b1b\maturin.exe build --target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc --release --strip --interpreter python --manifest-path python-package/Cargo.toml --sdist --out dist
 Building a mixed python/rust project
 Found pyo3 bindings
 Found CPython 3.9 at C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.13\x64\python.exe
 maturin failed
  Caused by: Failed to build source distribution
  Caused by: File perpetual-0.4.8\README.md was already added from D:\a\perpetual\perpetual\README.md, can't added it from D:\a\perpetual\perpetual\python-package\README.md
Error: The process 'D:\a\_temp\9ef7b44d-af79-42ba-9bdc-1eeb97741b1b\maturin.exe' failed with exit code 1
    at ExecState._setResult (D:\a\_actions\PyO3\maturin-action\v1\dist\index.js:1702:25)
    at ExecState.CheckComplete (D:\a\_actions\PyO3\maturin-action\v1\dist\index.js:1685:18)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\a\_actions\PyO3\maturin-action\v1\dist\index.js:1579:27)
Error: The process 'D:\a\_temp\9ef7b44d-af79-42ba-9bdc-1eeb97741b1b\maturin.exe' failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)

How can I solve this?
Github repo: https://github.com/perpetual-ml/perpetual
